# In Nomine Superiors for a Psychological/Surrealist Setting

Tags: in-nomine

I'm looking to create a psychological In Nomine setting based around Human Dreams and the Marches. What are the most usefulsuperiors to use for a comical/surrealist interpretation of the ethereal plane that stresses psychological ideas over direct conflict between opposing superiors?

Comment: Can you narrow this down so there might be a "correct" answer? Seems like this is more brainstorming.

Comment: "Best" usually involves personal judgement or taste. Can you define what "best" for this means *to you*, so that answers could have a chance of meeting that critierium without having to guess what makes a superior "best" to you for this?